# Doubt/confusion about commutative algebra exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This is from Altman & Kleiman's "A Term of Commutative Algebra". It is Exercise (3.10) in the 2017 edition.

Here is the exercise:

Let $\varphi: R \to R'$ be a ring map, $\mathfrak{p}$ an ideal of R. Show

(1) there is an ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of R' with $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}) = \mathfrak{p}$ if and only if $\varphi^{1}(\mathfrak{p}R') = \mathfrak{p}$.

(2) If $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime with $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}R') = \mathfrak{p}$, then there's a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of R' with $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}) = \mathfrak{p}$.

I verified (1) just fine. For (2), I looked at the solutions and the first step is to take $S = \varphi(R\setminus \mathfrak{p})$ and claim that $S \cap \mathfrak{p}R' = \emptyset$. If this were true the exercise can be finished by taking some ideal maximal w.r.t. being disjoint from $S$, and then noting that this ideal must be prime. However, I do not think this is (obviously) true? Can't something be in $\varphi(R\setminus \mathfrak{p})$ and also in $\varphi(\mathfrak{p})$?

On the other hand I have not yet been able to come up with a counterexample for (2).

Comment: In (2), you are told $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}R') = \mathfrak{p}$ by hypothesis, so no element of $R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ has image in $\mathfrak{p}R'$.

Comment: (For an easy counterexample if you do not include this extra condition, let $R$ be a ring, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal which is not maximal, and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{p}$. If $\varphi \colon R \to R/\mathfrak{m}$ is the canonical quotient map, then $\varphi(\mathfrak{p}) = 0$, but $\varphi^{-1}(0) = \mathfrak{m}$. And indeed, the only prime ideal of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is $\{0\}$, and so there is no prime ideal of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ whose preimage is $\mathfrak{p}$.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim woops, thank you!

Comment: Happens to all of us. Glad to help!